# Given the probability distribution calculate $σ_{XY}$

Tags: probability

[image]

How do I calculate the problem,  $σ_{XY}$ ?

Comment: Any try? What is the definition of $\sigma_{XY}$?

Comment: @zoli idk, it just showed up on my online homework and teacher never covered it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sigma_{XY}$ is the covariance. $$\begin{align}\sigma_{XY} ~ & = ~ \sum_{(x,y)}(x-\mathsf{E}X)(y-\mathsf{E}Y)P(x,y)\\[1ex] & =~ \sum_{(x,y)} xy\,P(x,y) ~-~\mathsf E X\cdot\mathsf EY\end{align}$$
Just substitute all $x$, $y$, and $P(x,y)$ values given in the table (as well as $\mathsf{E}X$ and $\mathsf{E}Y$ given in a.) in the sum. The sum will have $4$ terms.